# How to eliminate global variables

Tags: debugging, variables, go

I am just starting to learn go, and everywhere it is mentioned that for the best practices is recommended to avoid usage of global variables. I have this piece of code:

```
package main

const scriptVersion = "1.1"
var debug = 0

func logHandler(t, e string) {
    switch t {
    case "warning":
        fmt.Println("WARNING |", e)
    case "error":
        fmt.Println("ERROR   |", e)
        os.Exit("1")
    case "debug":
        if debug == 1 {
            fmt.Println("DEBUG   |", e)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println("INFO    |", e)
    }
}

for userOptsValue := range os.Args { {
        switch userOptsValue {
        case "-d", "--debug":
            d := &debug
            *d = 1
            logHandler("debug", "Debug Enabled")
        case "-v", "--version":
            logHandler("info", "Version "+scriptVersion)
        default:
            logHandler("warning", "Unknown Option "+userOptsValue+","+" ignoring")
        }
    }
```

The idea is to activate debug action in the script by calling the script with -d or --debug arguments. How can I do the same but avoiding global variable "var debug = 0" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the debug flag only affects your logging, create a

```
type logger struct {
    debug bool
}
```

which captures that state, then make your `logHandler` a method `log(...)` of that type.

This leaves the question where to create an instance of the `logger`. In the specific case of logging, which is often ubiquitous throughout the whole program, there are two possibilities that I can think of:

1) Use a global log variable/function, i.e. create one `logger` at the beginning of the program, then use that globally everywhere. This means you can put it in your own `log` package for example, like the built-in [package log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) (which by the way you could also use but I see how you often need something else for logging).

2) Again, have one `logger` instance but instead of making it globally available, pass it down to all the places you need to use it. Create it in your main and pass it to the sub-modules that need to use it. This is highly dependent on your code organization, sometimes it is easy to do this, sometimes not. In some cases, option 1) may work better for you.